# Repeated calls to a ray cluster from a flask app

Tags: python, flask, ray

I have a flask application that sometimes needs to execute some expensive python functions, so I connect it to a ray cluster:

```
import ray
import time

@bp.route("/generate_my_data/<int:uid>", methods="GET",))
def generate_uid_data(uid):
    generate_my_data(uid)
    return redirect(url_for("view_uid_data")), uid=uid)

def expensive(uid):
    # compute some expensive stuff and write to disk
    time.sleep(3)   


def generate_my_data(uid):
    ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        fields = get_fields_from_postgres(uid)
        for field in fields:
            ray.remote(expensive).remote(field)
```

The problem with this approach is that the connection to ray *stays open*, meaning that the job on the ray dashboard is always running, even once the expensive calls are done. This is not ideal, as the number of tasks associated with the job can grow quite large and doesn't really reflect the current state of work being done.

The naive solution to this is to `ray.get` some futures returned by the expensive function, and then call `ray.shutdown`. However, this is no good, because this is a flask app being served up. We may have multiple calls of `generate_my_data` running for different uids, and all associated tasks are cancelled as soon as `ray.shutdown` is called anywhere (I tried this out, remaining tasks fail when the connection is shutdown).

It doesn't seem like there is a trivial way to open different connections to ray from the same python process, and I didn't see many examples of using flask + ray out in the wild. So my question is: how can I work around this limitation? What is a good approach for connecting to a ray cluster from flask?